# Is close quarters combat with firearms in a confined space considered a hazardous task?

Tags: 2300ad

I know firing indoors has the potential to hit walls, hulls and equipment, but from the rules this is potentially an additional armor value if a player or npc has cover. I also see where some combat tasks are hazardous if untrained. What I can't find is if firing indoors should be considered hazardous and failures (or fumbles) roll on the failure and potentially mishap tables. (Like a hull breach if it penetrates or a ricochet otherwise.)

Is this covered anywhere? I have both the original Traveller 2300 rule books (Referee's and Players' guides) and the 2300AD CDROM canon (which includes the Adventurers' and Director's guides).

Traveller 2300 was renamed to 2300AD, some changes were made and quite a few rules were expanded or added. I'm only curious about Traveller 2300 independently if rules that cover this are only in one edition or are different between the editions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If they use hot weapons, or especially penetrative weapons, or if they fire at dangerous things. Richochets are not a noted issue.**

p8 of the Director's handbook notes this as an example.

> To disarm an unexploded warhead

Other examples include this, from the Kafer Sourcebook p56.

> Firing  a  Kafer  weapon  is
>   considered  "Hazardous,"  requiring   a   3D6   roll   on   the
>   Failure  fable.  Depending  on
>   the  situation,   mishaps  may
>   result  in  injury  to  the  character (trauma  from  the  recoil
>   in  firearms,  burns  from  unshielded  or  hot  surfaces  in
>   plasma   or  laser   weapons).

So, as a general principle, a hazardous task involves risk of explosions, recoil, burns or such, not accidentally shooting yourself. Is that likely to happen if you fire indoors, such as on a ship?

In some ships no. See p5 of Star Cruiser

> Some  ships  have  an  armored  hull.  If  so,  this  is  noted  on  the
>   ship  status  sheet.  Armor  protects  the  ship's  internal  components
>   from damage  but provides  no protection for surface fixtures. Thus,
>   a  hit on  a surface fixture of an  armored  ship  is resolved  normally.

An armored, military ship is certainly not going to be vulnerable to small fire. Are ships in general vulnerable to weapons fire? Maybe. See page 46 of the Nyoketundo sourcebook

> Practice  Lasers:
>     Three  laser weapons are  also  among  the gym
>   stores of the
>    Andrew Carnegie.
>     One Mueller-Rivera P-3 pistol and
>   two   Gonzalves-Brazilia   "Luce-3"    laser   rifles   are   used   for
>   marksmanship practice on  board by those persons with an interest
>   in shooting.  Practice lasers,  however, are not combat-ready. They
>   have  been  heavily  modified  to  make  them  no  more  harmful  than
>   a particularly bright flashlight, **since having  live laser weapons on
>   board could be very hazardous to everyone**.  It would be possible,
>   however, to reconvert these weapons to combat use (as described
>   in  Onboard  Systems).   Until  these  conversions  are  made,  the
>   weapons are  useless;  once  converted,  their stats  are as  given  in
>   the player handbook.

So, generally, combat inside with laser weapons or similar hot weapons (explosives, plasma weapons, heat weapons etc) should be considered generally hazardous if having things set on fire and burnt through. Combat around key systems should be considered more hazardous. If you open fire into your main reactor, more risk. Weapons with a more powerful penetrative capacity would also be more of a risk. Firing a high powered sniper rifle is more dangerous than firing a pistol.

It is a judgement call by the Referee, but, there are situations as above that make it more likely or less likely. Simply firing guns isn't an innate issue, but firing them around sensitive equipment may be, and firing exotic guns may be an issue.